# Vis.js - Get children of node

Tags: graph, children, vis.js-network, vis.js

I've created a hierarchical directed graph in Vis.js. Now, I want to extract the parents from a given node. How do I do this? I couldn't find a method in the documentation that allowed me to do this.

Answer (score 5):

As TERMIN had said, `vis.Network()` objects have a method `getConnectedNodes` for this purpose ([documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#methodInformation)). You don't need to use the `getPosition` method to differentiate children from parent nodes though, as TERMIN had said, because `getConnectedNodes` has an optional input for the edge direction that would cover this.

If your `vis.Network()` object is named network, then try:

```
var myNode = 'desired node ID',
    arrayOfParents = network.getConnectedNodes(myNode, 'from')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getConnectedNodes` method to get the connected nodes (parents and children).

Get the positions of the nodes using `getPosition` method.

Run over the connected nodes and see which node has `y` position smaller then the current node `y` position. This node should be the parent.

Same for all other found parents.